# Having trouble parsing this string into a date

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

In C#, I'm trying to parse a string using a custom pattern. The data will always be formatted as `"ddd,M/d"`, so I'm trying to use `TryParseExact`:

```
string date = "Wed 11/17";
string pattern = "ddd M/d";
DateTime dateresult;
bool test = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, pattern, new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out  dateresult);
```

Shouldn't test return `true`? I feel I'm missing something minor here.

Comment: Which Wednesday the 17th of November do you expect that to return. There's probably one every 5 or 6 years

Comment: The issue is that if you omit the year, the *current* year is assumed. I suspect you ran this in 2022, which means November 17th 2022, and this is a Thursday, not a Wednesday. If you try `"Wed 11/16"` instead, it will return `true`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`"ddd M/d"` This format is not acceptable in DateTime.TryParseExact();
for the reference please check  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-6.0

```
string date = "01/20/2022";
string pattern = "M/dd/yyyy";
DateTime dateresult;
bool test = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, pattern, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out dateresult);

// Return True;
```

Comment: Almost tempted to delete my question because I missed something so ridiculous as not having the year, but thank you for this answer.

Comment: Actually, that format *is* acceptable by `DateTime.TryParseExact`, the problem is that if you omit parts, like the year component, the current year is assumed. And 17th of November 2022 is a Thursday, not a Wednesday. If you try the original code and substitute the input string with `"Wed 11/16"`, then it returns `true`.

Comment: Specifically, the current year, month and day is assume depending on how many of the date components you omit.

Answer (score 0):

When your input string and pattern is missing some of the date components, the current year, month, and day, is assumed, depending on which components you are missing.

It will not go looking for the last time that particular date and day combination was valid.

So that parsing is looking for a Wednesday 17th of November in 2022, and that date is a Thursday, not a Wednesday. 16th, however, is a Wednesday, so if we just change the code slightly:

```
string date = "Wed 11/16"; // only changed 17 to 16
string pattern = "ddd M/d";
DateTime dateresult;
bool test = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, pattern, new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out dateresult);

Console.WriteLine($"{test}: {dateresult}");
```

Then it outputs:

```
True: 16.11.2022 00:00:00
```